# How can I find differences between two dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that I merged together on a common ID. I am trying to uncover when values in each row for a matching ID are different.

I merged the files so that I have the below table. I think I might be able to approach this with a series of if statements but the actual data file has hundreds of column attributes which doesn't seem efficient at all. I'm trying to determine if there's an easy way to do this.

```
x Loan_ID   Trade_Quantity_x    Principal_x Interest_x  Late_Fee_x  Trade_Quantity_y    Principal_y Interest_y  Late_Fee_y
0   1   10  30  0   0   10  30  0   0
1   2   10  0   0   5   10  0   0   0
2   3   10  0   50  0   10  0   0   0
3   4   10  0   0   0   10  0   0   0
4   5   10  100 10  0   10  100 10  0
5   6   9   0   0   0   9   0   0   0
6   7   10  0   0   0   10  0   0   0
```

Expected output should be:

```
2. Late_Fee_y
3. Interest_y
```

Comment: do not show picture , show your expected output here

Comment: I don't really understand how you get to that expected output. Which column represents the id based on which you want to do the comparison?

Comment: My expected output doesn't have to be that. I just need to calculate differences within each Loan_ID row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that what you are after is to compare two data frames of the same structure, i.e. having the same list of columns and the same number of rows identified by values of special `Loan_ID`.

The goal is to list all "cells" which are different between the two frames, cell location is by the id from Loan_ID and column name.

Can I suggest to merge the two frames differently first, to get a list of values and then find differences by scanning melted frames, or by applying a filter?

Example data (think of `id` as `Loan_ID`)

```
x = {'id':[1,2],'A':[0,1],'B':[2,3]}
y = {'id':[1,2],'A':[0,2],'B':[2,4]}
df_x = pd.DataFrame(x)
df_y = pd.DataFrame(y)
print(df_x)
print(df_y)
```

melted

```
df_xm = pd.melt(df_x, id_vars=['id'])
df_xm['source']='x'
df_ym = pd.melt(df_y, id_vars=['id'])
df_ym['source']='y'
print(df_xm)
print(df_ym)
```

Assuming that both frames are sorted by id correspondingly

```
for i in df_xm.index:
    if df_xm['value'][i] != df_ym['value'][i]:
        print(f"{df_xm['id'][i]},{df_xm['variable'][i]}")
```

Second method :

```
merged = df_xm.merge(df_ym, left_on= ['id','variable'], right_on=['id','variable'])
print(merged)
filter_diff = merged['value_x'] != merged['value_y']
print('differences:')
print(merged[ filter_diff ])
```

I'm sure this can be improved for efficiency but this is my general idea how to tackle the "difference between two table snapshots" with general frame/tables and filter operations.

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I apologize for the simple question. This is essentially what I'm trying to do. Would it be easy to manipulate this code to handle scenarios where one dataframe has more rows (IDs present in one but not the other) than another? Perhaps in that case I could run something that would keep just duplicate IDs..

Comment: Yes, the `merge` method with `how='outer'` argument added would produce a frame with ids and columns from both input tables. The filter then can be modified to accommodate comparison of `NaN` (missing data), see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html?highlight=isnull#pandas.DataFrame.isnull

Comment: how would I go about modifying that filter? Thank you

Comment: `merged[ merged['value_x'].isna()]` will give you ids and columns which do not appear in the `df_y`, and  `merged['value_y']` is the filter to get only rows of ids and columns (and values) for which there is no corresponding entry in `df_x`